# how to get address of buffer with JNIENV *env jni android

Tags: android, android-ndk

```
How to get the address in the NDK JNI android?
```

Their is one buffer which is passed from java class . in c code file i just want to know the address of the buffer which i have passed??? any idea?

Comment: First, show us what you've tried. Second, Java passes objects to JNI by reference and won't allow you to directly manipulate the contents. You need to copy the JAVA data to local native memory with the appropriate function (e.g. GetByteArrayRegion).

Comment: Are you looking for this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetDirectBufferAddress